# Why are my if statements only responding to the first measurement?

Tags: python

Thank you Whitebeard and everyone else ! functions properly now.

I have a function that measures the time it takes to charge a capacitor, then prints out that time at the end, which works as intended. I have 2 `if` statements that I need to update every cycle, but they only react to the very first measurement of the script. Any explanation for why this is would be greatly appreciated.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO, time
GPIO.setmode (GPIO.BOARD)

def RCtime(RCpin):
    reading = 0
    GPIO.setup (RCpin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output (RCpin, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(.1)
    GPIO.setup (RCpin, GPIO.IN)
    while (GPIO.input(RCpin) == GPIO.LOW):
        reading += 1
    return reading
if RCtime <= 300000:
    relay1 = true
if RCtime > 300000:
    relay1 = false

while 1:
    print RCtime() #works as intended
    print relay1  #only works for the first cycle
```

thus far, thats my entire code

Why does relay1 print the proper true/false statement the first cycle?
im not sure where my indents are wrong
initialize relay1 = None at the top?
even though "print RCtime()" does work currently, should i not use that function as a variable? how should i make it something different?
I very much appreciate all your help. im trying to grasp good fundamentals

Comment: please correct your indentation

Comment: relay1 needs to be initialized in your main function

Comment: So what are you meant to return if `RCTime == 300000`?

Comment: Also, I've corrected your grammar but I cannot touch your syntax.  Please be sure that your indentation is correct.

Comment: @JibSwitch if you hope to get any useful answer you will have to post a minimal complete verifiable example cf  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please remember to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have named a function `RCtime` with the same name as a variable `RCtime`:

```
def Recalltime(RCpin):
    ....
    return reading

while True:
    RCtime = Recalltime()
    print RCtime
    if RCtime < 300000:
        relay1 = true
    if RCtime > 300000:
        relay1 = false

    print relay1
```

There is also a secondary problem, as the behavior is undetermined (and `relay1` not assigned) when `RCtime` is exactly equal to `30000`. (mentioned by @Makoto in the comments)

Comment: maybe you should wait until the op fixed her code indentation before answering?

Comment: the code you are referring to is unreachable if indented

Comment: I see you changed your answer to be the same as mine after I posted.

Comment: I indeed, after reflexion, amended my answer for a better one... that, I see now, happens to be similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

To get it to read the if statements on every cycle:

```
def RCtime(RCpin):
    ....
    return reading


while 1:
    rctime = RCtime(RCpin_value) #note assign function result to variable with different name
    print rctime
    if rctime < 300000: #might want this to be 'if rctime <= 300000' to avoid having no value in the case of rctime == 300000
        relay1 = True #in Python Boolean values are capitalized
    if rctime > 300000: #might want this to be an elif statement to eliminate need to call this test in the case first test is true
        relay1 = False
    print relay1
```